# "error: expected primary-expression before 'volatile'"

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile [NRF driver](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/pc-ble-driver/tree/v0.5.0) with MinGW 4.8.2. I'm getting this error:

In file included from

```
b:/nrfdriver/sdk/nRF51_SDK_8.1.0_b6ed55f/components/device/nrf51.h:119:0,
                 from b:/nrfdriver/sdk/nRF51_SDK_8.1.0_b6ed55f/components/softdevice/s130/headers/nrf_soc.h:50,
                 from b:/nrfdriver/pc-ble-driver-0.5.0/driver/inc_override/nrf_soc.h:21,
                 from b:/nrfdriver/pc-ble-driver-0.5.0/driver/inc_override/app_util_platform.h:26,
                 from b:/nrfdriver/sdk/nRF51_SDK_8.1.0_b6ed55f/components/drivers_nrf/uart/app_uart.h:27,
                 from b:\nrfdriver\pc-ble-driver-0.5.0\driver\src\app_uart_pc.c:13:
C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/include/xmmintrin.h:
In function 'void _mm_setcsr(unsigned int)':
b:/nrfdriver/sdk/nRF51_SDK_8.1.0_b6ed55f/components/toolchain/gcc/core_cm0.h:164:21:
error: expected primary-expression before 'volatile'    #define   __I 
volatile             /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions   */
                     ^ driver\CMakeFiles\s130_nrf51_ble_driver.dir\build.make:297: recipe for
target 'driver/CMakeFiles/s130_nrf51_ble_driver.dir/src/app_uart_pc.c
.obj' failed
```

Error comes from this line:

```
#define   __I     volatile             /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions                 */
```

How can such a simple `#define` lead to a compiler error and any idea how I should fix that? (upgrading the compiler is not an option as this version of the driver is supposed to be built with this version of MinGW).

Note that the driver is meant to be built in 32bits and I'm trying to build it targetting 64bits, dunno if that could be the cause of the problem...

Comment: Does the error go away if you compile it for 32 bits instead of 64 bits?

Comment: maybe you need to try different compiler, or maybe try setting c version, I suppose you should have -std=c99

Comment: Can you show the relevant code on xmmintrin.h?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Did not test 32bits....they provide a binary for this target, so I don't need to compile it.

Comment: @imreal: You can see it here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-1762/gcc/config/i386/xmmintrin.h

Comment: @NathanOliver: Just tested that, posting only for the records: 32bits version compiles fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if we also look in the xmmintrin.h header?

```
/* Set the control register to I.  */
extern __inline void __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_mm_setcsr (unsigned int __I)
{
  __builtin_ia32_ldmxcsr (__I);
}
```

Ouch, another use of `__I`.

Comment: Damned, I posted my question too quickly. I'm not familiar with MinGW and I was almost sure it was a compiler issue. Apparently, it comes from the code itself. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: If anyone hits the same problem: I manually replaced all `__I` by `__NRF_I` in driver and SDK folder: it compiled fine then!